# java spring juint testing with MVC (@EnableWebMvc included to configuration)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, model-view-controller

I have configuration in a sample MVC application.
Whey I try to run it by Tomcat server it work perfectly.
Now I want to add some test and recive "No ServletContext set" error message. Withot @EnableWebMvc all ests are performed.

Now - it's configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore")
public class RootApplicationContextConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/springmvctest");
            dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
            dataSource.setPassword("12345");

            if (dataSource.getConnection().isClosed()) throw new Exception("Соединение закрыто");

        } catch (Throwable e) {

            final String msg = "Error" + ": " + EOS + e;    
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        return dataSource;

    } //END: mysqlDataSource()

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
            NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = null;    
        try {    
            template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(mysqlDataSource());    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + ": " + EOS + e);
        }

        return template;

    } //END: getJdbcTemplate()

} //END: class RootApplicationContextConfig
```

Web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.packt.webstore")
public class WebApplicationContextConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer
    ) {

        configurer.enable();

    } //END: configureDefaultServletHandling()

     @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {

        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;

    } //END: getInternalResourceViewResolver()

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {

        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();    
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);    
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);

    } //END: configurePathMatch()
```

And the test:

```
@Test
void ProductTest() throws Exception {

InMemoryProductRepository productRepository = null;
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RootApplicationContextConfig.class);
productRepository = context.getBean(InMemoryProductRepository.class);
Assertions.assertNotEquals(null, productRepository);
List<Product> list_of_products = productRepository.getAllProducts();
Assertions.assertNotEquals(null, list_of_products);
Assertions.assertNotEquals(0, list_of_products.size());
context.close();

} //END: ProductTest()
```

There the error message than I recive when @EnableWebMvc is present:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: dbtest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.547 s <<< FAILURE! - in dbtest
dbtest.ProductTest  Time elapsed: 0.515 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at dbtest.ProductTest(dbtest.java:30)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at dbtest.ProductTest(dbtest.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at dbtest.ProductTest(dbtest.java:30)
```

**How to run juint tests when @EnableWebMvc is present? How to provide the servlet context during a test phase?**

Comment: Why are you doing this in a new project instead of using Spring Boot, which is the modern standard?

Comment: Yes. I learn spring without springboot.

Comment: Don't do that. Spring Boot was invented so that this would not be necessary, and it has been the standard for several years.

Comment: These errors generallly come from the fact that one is mixing jars from different Spring versions. Check your dependencies. Also your `@Configuration` annoated class is flawed, don't catch the exception but let Spring handle them (else you get an application in an illegal state) and you are leaking a connction in your datasource method (if you do `getConnection` you should also close it) also it doesn't test anything, so remove it.